# MySQL JOIN Complexity

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am using MySQL 5.5 and have two tables T1(ID, NAME) and T2(ID, MARKS), following is the data in the table.

T1's data

```
ID NAME
1  A
2  B
3  C
```

T2's data

```
ID MARKS
1  40
5  60
```

AND I want following resultset

```
ID NAME MARKS
1  A    40
2  B    0
3  C    0
```

What query we can write to accomplish above resultset?

Comment: http://www.khankennels.com/blog/index.php/archives/2007/04/20/getting-joins/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` the two tables:

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  t1.name,
  IFNULL(t2.Marks, 0) AS Marks
FROM T1 
LEFT JOIN T2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bcbb5/1)

Comment: Thanks for making me discover SQLFiddle! Great site :)

Answer (score 3):

You should be using a `LEFT JOIN` clause for this kind of result :-)

Your query will look like this :

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    NAME, 
    COALESCE(MARKS, 0) AS MARKS
FROM T1
    LEFT JOIN T2 USING(ID)
```

Note that I'm using the `USING` clause for a more semantic and compact syntax than the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you need to use `LEFT JOIN` to join both tables since it is not guaranteed that `ID` on table `T1` will exist on table `T2`. `LEFT JOIN` retrieves all rows that are found on the *lefthand side* table whether it has a matching record or not on the *righthand side* table.

The use of `COALESCE` in the statement is to convert `NULL` values into `0`. The reason why `NULL` exist on the values of the column is because some records on table `T1` doesn't have a matching record on table `T2` causing the column `T2.Marks` to be null.

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.Name, COALESCE(b.Marks, 0) Marks
FROM    T1 a
        LEFT JOIN T2 b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f2f2/1)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)